# Normal 'def' function instead of lambda

Tags: python, lambda, folium

The following code produces a web map with countries colored by population which values come from world.json.

```
import folium

map=folium.Map(location=[30,30],tiles='Stamen Terrain')

map.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=open('world.json', encoding='utf-8-sig'),
name="Unemployment",
style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor':'green' if x['properties']['POP2005'] <= 10000000 else 'orange' if 10000000 < x['properties']['POP2005'] < 20000000 else 'red'}))

map.save('file.html')
```

Link of [world.json](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hztkqnpnh1u5nag/world.json?dl=0).

I was wondering if it's possible to use a normal function created with `def` instead of a lambda function as the value of the `style_function` argument. I tried creating a function for that:

```
def feature(x):
    file = open("world.json", encoding='utf-8-sig')
    data = json.load(file)
    population = data['features'][x]['properties']['POP2005']
    d ={'fillColor':'green' if x['properties']['POP2005'] <= 10000000 else 'orange' if 10000000 < x['properties']['POP2005'] < 20000000 else 'red'}
    return d
```

However, I can't think of how to use it in `style_function`. Is this possible or is the lambda function irreplaceable here?

Comment: You mean `style_function = feature` ?

Comment: Or just `def style_function` instead of `def feature` ? Where does `style_function` even get used?

Comment: Also - do you really want the opening and loading of the json file every time that function is called? Surely - you want to do that part once and then use the function to get a style for `x` whatever that is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `style_function` lambda can be replaced with a function like this:

```
def style_function(x):
    return {'fillColor':'green' if x['properties']['POP2005'] <= 10000000 else 'orange' if 10000000 < x['properties']['POP2005'] < 20000000 else 'red'}))
```

Then you can just pass the function name to the kwarg:

```
folium.GeoJson(
    data=...,
    name=...,
    style_function=style_function
)
```

Comment: `style_function` is being used as a `kwarg` for `GeoJson`

Comment: Ohhhh, you're right.  The formatting didn't make that clear, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, you need to make function like this one (`x` is the geojson):

```py
def my_style_function(x):
    color = ''
    if x['properties']['POP2005'] <= 10e6:
        color = 'green'
    elif x['properties']['POP2005'] < 2*10e6:
        color = 'orange'
    return {'fillColor': color if color else 'red'}
```

and simply assign it to the `style_function` parameter (without the parenthesis):

```py
map.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=open('world.json', encoding='utf-8-sig'),
                             name="Unemployment",
                             style_function=my_style_function))
```